# How to do live presentation (.pptx or .ppt) in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, http-live-streaming, live-streaming, presentation

I am having bit trouble. I need to know how can I do the live presentation(.pptx or .ppt) on the website. I am searching for it for past 4 days and recently I found one site which is doing the exact thing what I am looking for but it have lack of support and it doesn't support Firefox browser and  there is no API for it. So what I need to it with IFrame. Here the reference link what am I try to achieve.

https://presentation.io

Hope you will understand the thing I am looking for and provide some useful suggestion to me. Thanks.

Comment: Try [this](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-display/documents-cloud-based/22977), [this](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-display/documents-cloud-based/16126) and [this](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-display/documents-cloud-based/7871). I haven't tried any of them so not sure if they are exactly what you're looking for. Also have a look at [Slidershare.net](http://www.slideshare.net/) as I think it provide an embed code which you can simply use in your Joomla article

Comment: @Lodder have you see the link https://presentation.io , that is what I am looking for ,where if you upload a presentation(ppt) and start processing and if you share this link to some one then whatever action you will perform like change the slide and stop it it will also reflect to others screen as well. Hope you have any suggestion to do it like that in Joomla or any other solution.

Comment: Ah no, I don't know of any extensions for Joomla that do this. It would need to be a custom component.

Comment: @Lodder Ok, So if you know something about how can i do live sharing with php, Joomla or any other technology which is compatible to php, It would be really helpful. I am also referring your link you have provided. thanks for it.